# LoggerContext import fails for log4j 2.17.1 in spite of adding Maven dependency

Tags: java, maven, log4j, log4j2, maven-dependency

I am trying to use [LoggerContext](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/LoggerContext.html#setConfigLocation%28java.net.URI%29) in my Java code.

Added the Maven dependency in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.1</version>
</dependency>
```

The piece of code that I am trying to add:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext;
LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
File file = new File("path/to/a/different/log4j2.xml");
```

However, my `import` statement errors out. I am using IntelliJ IDE and the 'Add Maven Dependency' option in the IDE that searches for the class also doesn't return any results for `org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext`

I tried re-building the project from the IDE, but, that didn't help.

What am I missing?

Comment: Try: 1. Build on command line. Inspect output. 2. Reload All Maven Projects on Maven tab in IntelliJ

Comment: This worked. Can you please post this as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code looks good to my eyes, most likely IntelliJ hasn't pulled in the dependency.

To diagnose:

- run build via `mvn install` on command line. Inspect the output. If the build passes, this will limit the problem to IntelliJ
- use `Reload All Maven Projects` on Maven tab in IntelliJ